# AWS codepipeline failling

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

[image]

```
 sudo yum update
sudo yum install ruby
sudo yum install wget
cd /home/ec2-user
wget https://codepipeline-us-east-1-12345556.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/latest/install
chmod +x ./install
sudo ./install auto
sudo service codedeploy-agent start
```

and roles assigned properly, ec2 is linex.
took the sample code from
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-simple-codecommit.html

s3 buket policy

{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "AllowPublicReadAccess",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": "*",
"Action": [
"s3:PutObject",
"s3:ListBucket",
"s3:GetObject",
"s3:DeleteObject"
],
"Resource": [
"arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-us-east-1-12345556",
"arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-us-east-1-12345556/*"
]
}
]
}

Comment: Do you have any logging enabled that might help explain the failure? I found this page: [Logging and monitoring in CodePipeline - AWS CodePipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/incident-response.html)

Comment: Please login to the instance (via SSH) and review these logs:
*** /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-group-ID/deployment-ID/logs/scripts.log
*** /var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log

Comment: @shariqmaws find / -name "*.log" i ran this command did not find opt folder and permission denied for every file

Comment: i found the issue sericeRole is not created properly